# congratulate user when viewgroup is empty

Tags: android, null, viewgroup

im new to android and ive made a few small activities that show shapes that can be dragged and dropped onto its appropriate place holder if they match the shape stays and if it doesnt it pings back to where it was but i cant figure out how to tell when the view group is empty as null has to be declared and isnt it own state if ive got that right can anyone help all im after is a simple kind of, if/else viewgroup == null do.... animation can somebody shed some light on this for me?

here is what i have

```
public class PuzzleActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {
View topLevelLayout;
HorizontalScrollView from;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage2).setOnTouchListener(this);

    findViewById(R.id.squareImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage3).setOnDragListener(this);
    topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
    from = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView) ;

    if (isFirstTime()) {
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {

    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        if (from.getChildCount() == 1){ Toast zToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "YOU GENIUS :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); zToast.show(); }

        if(view.getId()==R.id.squareImage && v.getId()==R.id.squareImage1)
        {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.topleftcoat);
            Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Well Done! :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            myToast.show();
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.circleImage && v.getId()==R.id.circleImage1){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toprightcoat);
            Toast aToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Well Done! :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            aToast.show();
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.triangleImage && v.getId()==R.id.triangleImage1){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottomleftcoat);
            Toast bToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Well Done! :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            bToast.show();
            return true;
        }else if(view.getId()==R.id.triangleImage2 && v.getId()==R.id.triangleImage3){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottomrightcoat);
            Toast cToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Well Done! :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            cToast.show();
            return true;

        }

        else {
            Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oops! Try again :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            newToast.show();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.reset:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);



    }
}
public void onClick2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PuzzleActivity2.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        topLevelLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
    return ranBefore;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the getChildCount() method on your ViewGroup instance to determine the number of children left.

Comment: thank you ive searched on this am i looking for something like

Comment: sorry thank you ive just went and searched on this and tried to implement it i tried final int count = getChildCount(); and if getChildCount()=0 but it just flags me a bunch of errors and i dont see how to tell it its looking for viewgroup from my best resource on this seems to be http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html but im unsure as my ide says it cannot resolve getChildCount

Comment: Since your count value will be  changing, you won't be able to use 'final'. assuming 'from' is the name of your ViewGroup, you need to use something like `if (from.getChildCount() == 0)`.

Comment: i changed the viewgroup name to container and tried your answer i get no errors but it also doesnt fire this is my code.               if (container.getChildCount() == 0){
                Toast zToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "YOU GENIUS :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                zToast.show();
            }

Comment: Try toasting or logging the actual value returned from that call each time you move a shape. You should see the value change if you're making the correct call on the correct ViewGroup.

Comment: tried and it closed the app thank you though will keep trying

Comment: W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-16 00:29:04.765    4498-4498/com.martinsapp.socialstories W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4154c8b0)E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:246)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)

Comment: That shows that's there's something wrong a string used in your Toast message. What's the message used for the Toast?

Comment: (getApplicationContext(), "YOU GENIUS :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); zToast.show(); the getApplicationContext isnt giving it anything i dont think

Comment: went back to from and managed to get it to fire but only if it is == 1 it fires when the first piece is added?   if (from.getChildCount() == 1){ Toast zToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "YOU GENIUS :-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); zToast.show(); }

Comment: updated my code the genius toast fires when i move the first shape is it something to do with my condition always being true and therefore is always 1?

Comment: And less than a month I later I solved it using your solution thanks